# Can a sharded Mongo database be split (mongos and mongod) between Windows and Linux?

Tags: mongodb

As a proof of concept kind of project, I have set up a sharded MongoDB, with only two shards, and three servers running mongos instances. All of these are on their own Windows servers, but I'd like to try running the cluster on Linux systems, because I'm seeing some strange behaviour that I think *may* be related to the fact that the systems are all running on VMs on a corporate ESX server. Also, I'm just curious.

After reading as much documentation as I could find, I've found that the "mongos" instances that dispatch queries to the proper shards are lightweight and can typically be run on an application server or a system with a mongod instance ([documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/#start-the-mongos-instances)).

**My question is**, can MongoDB be configured so that the **mongos** instances run on a Windows server, while the **mongod** instances (the shards) be run on a Linux system? Would the **mongos** instances still be able to dispatch queries to the Shards?

One reason this would be beneficial in my case is that my application is a .Net web API, that I want to host in IIS, so it has to run on Windows. The benefit to running shards on Linux, which may be an incorrect assumption, is that a Linux system requires less overhead than Windows server, meaning it would be less expensive if it were run on a VM from a cloud provider.

Comment: Theoritically there is nothing stopping you since the machines would communicate over a standardised protocol

Comment: The only problems I can foresee are the headaches you'll most likely get when trying to maintain these systems :P Other than that, @Sammaye is correct: It doesn't matter as long as the instances are able to communicate with each other. IE correct IP's, ports, firewall setup, etc...

Comment: @Lix: What headaches? I don't see why having a heterogeneous infrastructure would require much more maintenance than a homogeneous one?

Comment: @mnemosyn - It was (mostly) a joke. I guess there are some other requirements/limitations that prevent the OP from using the same or similar hosts for all instances...

Comment: We have seen that if the mongo db version (even minor) is different in a cluster (also mongos) it could run into issues. Other wise it should be work. Have you tried this, are you facing any issues?

Comment: @gTito: I likely won't try this in the near future but I wanted to at least consider it for a project further down the road.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why this should not work.

MongoDB clusters communicate via network. They aren't even aware of the operating systems other members of the cluster or replica-set run on. But keep in mind that a heterogeneous architecture has quite some maintenance problems:

- All members of the database must have the same version to work together properly. That means you need to update all at the same time. Different operating systems add unnecessary complexity to this.
- MongoDBs processes might have different performance characteristics when they run on different platforms. This makes load-balancing a lot harder (but also opens up new possibilities)
- Lots of other reasons the guys on [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com) can explain much better than us.

By the way, virtualizing a heavy-duty database server is usually not a good idea. Any application where disc IO is the bottleneck runs much better on the bare metal (according to the sysadmins, which you will find on serverfault, not on stackoverflow).

Comment: That's an interesting point about running a virtualized heavy-duty database server. To add to that, running a database on a VM adds complexity around monitoring things like disk IO, especially when you don't have access to the (ESX) cluster that the VM is running on.